# Vue3 datepicker: scoped styles not working

Tags: css, vuejs3, vuepic-vue-datepicker

I am using [Vuepic/ Vue3Datepicker](https://vue3datepicker.com/installation/) and I want to customize the way a selected date looks like. As per the [documentation](https://vue3datepicker.com/customization/theming/), we can do that this way for the light mode:

```css
<style>
.dp__theme_light {
  --dp-highlight-color: rgba(34, 233, 8, 0.993);
  --dp-primary-color: #ff006f;
  --dp-primary-text-color: #000078;
}
</style>
```

This works fine except this applies to all the component where I use this date picker:

[image]

The solution is to write:

```css
<style scoped>
  ...
</style>
```

but this does not work at all: the style does not apply neither in this specific component nor elsewhere. id est, I the default theme colors apply in this case, and mine are ignored:

[image]

Anything I missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scoped CSS to affect child components target a class on the root child element and use the [:deep()](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors) selector on the class you actually want to target

```css
<style scoped>
.dp__main :deep(.dp__theme_light) {
  --dp-highlight-color: rgba(34, 233, 8, 0.993);
  --dp-primary-color: #ff006f;
  --dp-primary-text-color: #000078;
}
</style>
```